# Trying to generate id number + 1 from highest id in xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml

This is my code:

```
import os
import math
from xml.dom import minidom

XMLPath = "ClientIndex.xml"
xmldoc = minidom.parse(XMLPath)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('pair:id')
for i in itemlist:
    clientIDs = i.attributes['pair:id'].value
clientIDMax = max(clientIDs)
CIDnewTick = '1'
CIDnew = adding(clientIDMax , CIDnewTick)
print (CIDnew)
```

and it is spitting back

```
Traceback (most recewnt call last):
  file "testidcount.py", line 10, in <module>
     clientIDMax = max(clientIDs)
NameError: name 'clientIDs' is not defined
```

What is throwing me off is that it is defined in the loop. What is my addled brain missing?

The XML file in question is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- ClientIndex.xml -->
<clients>
    <client>
        <id>0</id>
        <nLast>Doe</nLast>
        <nMid>Test</nMid>
        <nFirst>Jane</nFirst>
        <filename>0-DoeJane.xml</filename>
    </client>
</clients>
```

Comment: There's no `pair:id` element in the sample, just `id`

Comment: Thank you; that was a daft  oversight on my part. Having fixed that, however, I am getting KeyError: 'id'  now